# Find a comment (username known) on an old question posted by me

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, search

I have about 220 questions on Stack Overflow and am looking to find a comment by someone whose username I know. The comment was posted against one of the answers to my question.

Is there an efficient way to filter my own posts to accommodate this type of search? Any pointers would be appreciated. It would be very helpful to be able to revisit a comment later while not remembering which question it was made against.

I have already visited the user's profile but since he has thousands of answers :) that wasn't much help either.

**Disclaimer:** Very new to the SE meta sites so please let me know in case this is the wrong kind of question to ask here. Also, I was not sure how to tag this question properly.

Comment: Someone may come up with a clever Data Explorer query. Failing that, I would Google for "(name of user) (your name) (any keywords you can remember) site:stackoverflow.com"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have visited their profile then presumably you can discover the actual specific userid not just the (not necessarily unique) user name?

In that case you can use [this Data Explorer Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/173860/comments-to-answers-to-my-questions-by-specific-user?CommenterUserId=938668&UserId=938668)

Currently set to find comments by **you** to answers to your own questions. Change the `CommenterUserId` parameter as required.

Comment: Yes, by username I meant their unique SE Id. I read somewhere long ago that the SE folks know how to put a Q&A site together. That comment has held up like nobody's business. Thank you for introducing me to the `Data Explorer` feature!